# Cometchat install into third subfolder for social engine 3?

Tags: socialengine

i am installing cometchat 3.0 for social engine 3 but the problem is the chat is located www.domain.com/folder/social-engine/chat/

Because cometchat is not in the first subfolder, it's not working and the admin page is blank. Can anyone tell me what files i need to change so that it can connect to db and start working?

I found this in config.php:

/* SOFTWARE SPECIFIC INFORMATION (DO NOT TOUCH) */

include dirname(**FILE**).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'integration.php';

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* BASE URL START */

define('BASE_URL','/chat/');

/* BASE URL END */

/* DATABASE */

include_once dirname(dirname(**FILE**)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."/include/database_config.php";

Is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

make changes to the following line define('BASE_URL','/chat/'); as 
follows

define('BASE_URL','/folder/social-engine/chat/');
Hope it works any other problem please ask at romeosameul@gmail.com